# How to properly dispose of datatable and tableadapter?

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

I have some code that retrieves a datatable, processes the data in the table, and then supposedly releases all resources again. I am wondering whether it indeed is guaranteed to properly dispose of all resources.

Reason for asking is that I thought the code was fail-safe, but apparently it does not properly dispose resources when renaming the table. I know this because the access database that it connects to retains a record lock after the code has executed.

Edit: Why does this code keep the connection to the database open after executing when I use the table rename, and how can I be sure that all resources are correctly disposed of without the rename?

```
try
{
   using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
   {
      using (var table = new DataSet.PartsDataTable())
      {
        //table.TableName = @"AltName";  // This messes up release of resources
        using (var partAdapter = new PartsTableAdapter())
        {
          try
          {
             partAdapter.Connection = conn;
             partAdapter.Fill(table);
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {               
              throw new Exception("test");
          }
        }
        foreach(var row in table)
        {
           //Process the rows. 
        }
      }
   }
}
catch(exception e)
{ 
    //Handle. 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where PartsDataTable and PartsTableAdapter types are defined? If they implement `IDisposable`, then you can use `using` clause.

Comment: You don't need to dispose a `DataTable`(or `DataSet`) and the table adapter. They don't hold any unmanaged resources. The table-adapter holds the DataAdapter but always disposes it property after usage and the DataTable just implements it to support drag&drop capabilities on the dataset-designer(comes from `IComponent`).

Comment: You don't need to dispose it.. "The Dispose method in DataSet exists ONLY because of side effect of inheritance-- in other words, it doesn't actually do anything useful in the finalization."
http://web.archive.org/web/20100724023926/http://www.developerdotstar.com/community/node/247

Comment: *but apparently it does not properly dispose resources when renaming the table* - Why should it dispose when you change the `TableName` Property of the `DataTable` object ?

Comment: So from the "should I Dispose() dataset and datatable" question I see that I might not even need to use the using statements. Still, my code somehow doesn't close the connection under some circumstances, at least not until I close the application? So I guess my question is how can this happen, and how do I prevent it from happening in the future?